# Can I generate a value in an installer and write it to the app.config?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, custom-action

I'm working on an installer project, during the install process I'd like the user to create a "root" account. I'd like to have the root password become a part of the app.config's file, preferably the encrypted section. Is such a thing possible? Are there any known solutions to this problem?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The App.Config is nothing more than an XML file.  After you place the app.config in the appropriate place in the installation process, just create an action (either execute a program or a script) in the installer which updates the app.config with the appropriate value.

Custom Actions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066(VS.85).aspx

Executing a program with a custom action:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368563.aspx